# Paint certain words in google docs - Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-apps

I have this code below:

```
        var textToHighlight = 'Normal';
        var highLightStyle = {};
        highLightStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = '#FFC0CB';
        var paras = doc.getParagraphs();
        var textLocation = {};

        for (i=0; i<paras.lenght; i++) {
          textLocation = paras[i].findText(textToHighlight);
          if (textLocation != null && textLocation.getStartOffset() != -1) {
            textLocation.getElement().setAttributes(textLocation.getStartOffset(), textLocation.getEndOffsetInclusive(), highLightStyle);
          }
        }
```

With it, I want to color all the words 'normal' that appear in my document, but when I run the code, nothing happens and it doesn't accuse any error, it compiles normally.

I tried this another code:

```
        let pinkColor = "#FFC0CB"
        let pinkElements = body.findText("Normal")
        let elem = pinkElements.getElement().asText();
        let t = elem.getText();
        elem.setForegroundColor(t.indexOf('Normal'), t.indexOf('High')+3, pinkColor)
```

But with the code above it paints only the first word 'Normal' that it finds, the rest remains neutral.

Does anyone know what may be happening to both codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know what may be happening to both codes?

**Code 1:**

You made a typo, `lenght` should be `length`.

**Code 2:**

See my answer below.

### Explanation:

You need to iterate over all elements with the particular keyword.

To achieve that you need to follow these steps:

1. get the first found element:

   `pinkElement = body.findText(searchWord);`
2. check if an element with `searchWord` exists
3. do some code for this element
4. assign a new element which is the next one you found before:

   `pinkElement = body.findText(searchWord, pinkElement);`
5. repeat steps 1-4 until there is no other element:

   `while (pinkElement != null)`

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {
   let doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
   let body = doc.getBody();
   let pinkColor = "#FFC0CB";
   let searchWord = "Normal";
   let pinkElement = body.findText(searchWord);
   while (pinkElement != null) {
     let elem = pinkElement.getElement().asText();
     let t = elem.getText();
     elem.setForegroundColor(t.indexOf(searchWord), t.indexOf('High')+3, pinkColor);
     pinkElement = body.findText(searchWord, pinkElement);
   }
}
```

Comment: It worked correctly @Marios! But in the answer below, I realized that I had spelled the word lenght wrong! When I fixed it, the code worked correctly too!

Comment: @Rafael I made the answer complete :) I just used the second code because it is more clear.

Comment: Thank you so much @Marios! I use your code in mine! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised it is returning the first one. "length" is spelled wrong on this line:

```
for (i=0; i<paras.**lenght**; i++) {
```

See if changing it to ".length" fixes it. If not, there is a similar example in the Docs at [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range) you could use.

Comment: hahahaha thank you Clark! I didn't see that. When i change, it works!

Comment: ok good! Always good to know your logic is sound and it is just a silly error! :)